# How can I add cars to my garage in Forza Horizon 2?

Tags: forza-horizon-2

When I go to the Garage, I only see 3 cars, 2 of which I've gotten from Wheel Spins. I haven't won hardly any races.

However, I did have some credits. So I bought some cars. But when I go to the Garage, they aren't there.

I don't understand how to actually drive these cars. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pause menu, there should be a section that says 'My Cars'. Click on it and all of the cars you have bought or won should be in there.

If you click on a car it will give you different options and one of them is "Get in car" and that should let you drive that car.